# if $f$ is such that $f(x)\ln(x) \leq 1$ then $\lim f(x) = ?$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions

I found this exercise: Le $f$ be a function and $f(x)\ln(x)\leq 1$ (I am not sure that this is the whole set of hypothesis). Calculate $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$.

Firstly I observed that for $f(x)=0$ and $f(x)= \dfrac{1}{k \ln(x)}$ with $k\geq 1$. we have  ? = 0. So my idea was to prove that such limit is 0.

Secondly I observed that

$\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) [ = ] \lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{f(x)\ln(x)}{\ln(x)} \leq \lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{1}{\ln(x)} = 0$

And from now on, I have two questions:

1. The $[=]$ is feasible? I think so because $\ln(x)\neq 0$ near 0.
2. How can I show $\geq $ in order to prove my conjecture?

Thank you all!

Comment: Any function that's positive on the interval $(0, 1]$ will satisfy the hypothesis there, because $\ln x$ is negative.

Comment: $\ln x <0$ if $x < 1$ so $\frac {f(x)\ln x}{\ln (x)} \ge \frac 1{\ln x}$ if $x < 1$.  And $\lim f(x)$ could be anything non-negative (or not exist).  Ex.  $f(x) = 27$ if $x < 1$ are $f(x)=\frac 1{x^{57}}; x< 1$ or $f(x)= x^2 + 9; x < 1$ or $f(x) = \sin \frac 1x$ etc all have positive or no limits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $0 < x < 1$ then $\frac 1{\ln x} <0$ and $\frac {f(x)}=\frac {f(x)\ln(x)}{\ln x} \ge \frac 1{\ln x}$.

So if the limit exists (no reason it should) it is non-negative.

And on the interval $(0,1]$ the only requirement we have is that $f(x) > \frac 1{\ln x}$ we can pretty much have the limit of $f(x)$ be anything non negative we like.  Why not $f(0) = 37,259$ for a continuous function on the interval $[0,1]$.  (Example:  $f(x) = -37,259x + 37,259$.....)

But you have proven if $f(x) < 0$ and $f(x)\ln x \le 1$ then $\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x) = 0$ which makes for a good excercise.